# Backbutton With Ajax loading Content

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, browser-history

This will load the content to the page and change the URL. The problem is that the back button and the forward won't load the content agin. They only change the URL. How can I make them load the function?

```
 <a onclick="load_content('p1');" >Page1</a>
 <a onclick="load_content('p2');" >Page2</a>



function load_content(name)
    {

    window.history.pushState(null, null, "/?page=" + name + "");

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {

        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","load_content.php?name=" + name + "",true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `history.pushState`, save all relevant data that is dynamic and then listen to the `popState` event and replace all elements just like you would do with AJAX.

Comment: can you post some example ive been trying to listen with popstate but i cant find a way to do so, thanks for your time!

Comment: But instead of taking the static data (the innerHTML from the link), store all dynamic data in the pushState and retrieve it in the popState.